# Can a parent class have a parent method that appends extra functionality?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, language-agnostic

I have a parent class called `Question`. There are many types of questions.

One of them is `MultipleChoice`. All child question classes like `MultipleChoice` has a method called `generate_response` which returns a json object with all the parts the rest of my app requires to produce the question.

In an effort to make my app DRY'er, I've notice that several of the items in this returned JSON object are similar calls. For example, the `:title` is always the `title` of the child class.

Is there a way I could write a parent method inside of `Question` that would append this static info into its JSON return from `generate_response`

Example :

```
class MultipleChoice < Question
  def generate_response
    {
      title: title
      explanation: explanation
      first_time: check_if_first
    }
  end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
 # is there a way inside of this class to append my static info to any child class usage of the method `generate_response`?
```

Comment: What purpose does language-agnostic tag serves here?

Comment: General relation to `super` in methods. I imagined this question is shared by most programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of `super`.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  def generate_response(obj)
    static info
  end
end

class InheritsFromQuestion < Question
  def generate_response
    super(self) #this will call the parent class (Question) method
    rest of whatever
  end
end
```